# how to create plugins for different audio software like itunes and winamp?

Tags: testing, audio, plugins, itunes, winamp

i am new to programming and want to develop  a plugin that interacts with the itunes or winamp ar WMP and then does what it is programmed to do. I know php and mysql kind of stuff but i am totally new at programming for pc. my question is that how to start where to start and anything i should keep in mind . Stuff like best language to learn to do so. I know a little basic python .can it be used for making plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start writing simple dll's (you can also write simple aplication to load and execute dll's procedures). Next step is to program better dll's (mor functionality etc.). There is a plenty of tutorials on this matters. And then you should read api documentation for  application you're writing plugin to (for winamp check this site: http://dev.winamp.com/plugin-developers)